# Remove "FacebookMessenger" from indicator-messages menu

Tags: applet, facebook, indicator-message

I have uninstalled a Facebook Messenger app, but it has left behind a menu item in the indicator-messages menu, as shown below:

[image: FacebookMessenger menu item]

How can I remove this menu item?

Comment: In English please.

Comment: I've attempted to translate it with Google Translate; hopefully, none of the original meaning was lost in translation

Comment: @zhongfu seems to make sense, Alejandro Escobar How did you uninstall it ?

Comment: @AlejandroEscobar could you point us to the application that caused this?

Comment: The horrible web-app facebook messenger